# Finding the double integral using polar coordinates.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

[image]

Above is the graph I have obtained from the equation.

Hi there so I've just been introduced to using polar co-ordinates to find double integrals and Im having a hard time working out how to tackle questions step by step.

Im currently looking at the question:

$I_{6}=\int\int_{Q}x/\pi (x^{2}+y^{2}) dxdy$ with $Q=\{(x,y)|(x-3/2)^2 +y^2 \leq9/4, y\geq0\}$

And Im struggling to make a start to this as I dont know how to obtain the limits of the double integral from $Q$ .

All I know is that I should eventually obtain the answer 3/4.

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Update:

So I now have the double integral

$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{3cos\theta}(rcos\theta/\pi)*((rcos\theta)^{2}+(rsin\theta)^{2}) rdrd\theta$

Comment: Have you written down the equation of the region in polar form, which is a circle with center at $(3/2, 0)$?

Comment: No I haven't . I dont actually know how to do that. Could you explain any further on how to do this please.

Comment: Equation of your region $Q$ will be $r = 3 \cos \theta$ in polar form $(0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2)$.

Comment: Thanks. So should my equation look like $I_{6}=\int\int_{Q} (rcos\theta)/(\pi) ((rcos\theta)^2+(rsin\theta)^2) drd\theta$ ?

Comment: Okay thank you and what would my limits be for r dr. I think from your comments the limit for $d\theta$ will be 0 and $\pi/2$

Comment: Thanks and sorry one last question. How did you work out the equation of the region in you second comment.

Answer (score 1):

On your specific question about how the equation in polar form becomes $r = 3 \cos \theta$,

In polar form, $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$

Now your curve is $(x-3/2)^2 +y^2 = 9/4 \implies x^2 + y^2 = 3x$

$r^2 cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta = 3r \cos \theta$

$r^2 = 3r \cos \theta \implies r = 3 \cos \theta$

Here is a diagram showing how $r$ changes with $\theta$ with $x$-axis.

[image]

Comment: Cheers, so I have worked out the first integral and wondered if you could tell me if my working is correct or not before moving on as Im struggling to achieve the next integral from this. $sin^2(\theta)9cos^3(\theta)+{81cos^7(\theta)/4\pi}$

Comment: That does not seem right. $r^2 cos^2\theta + r^2\sin^2\theta$ will simply give you $r^2$. So simplify and then integrate.

Comment: Thank you, can I ask why it is $r^4$ rather than $r^3$ seeing as we are multiplying $rcos(\theta)/\pi$ by $r^2$?

Comment: what about the $r$ from the Jacobian? :) Always remember in polar $dx \, dy$ is $r \, dr \, d\theta$.

Comment: You can also sketch and try to see $dA$ in terms of $r, \theta$. It will be clear why $dA = r \, dr \, d\theta$.

Comment: Ah I completely forgot about that thank you! So my first integral should become ${243/5}cos^{6}\theta$? And then I integrate with respect to $\theta$

Comment: Sorry to ask again but how do you know that $r=3cos\theta$ is in polar form $(0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2)$ .

Comment: The $(0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2)$ part.

Comment: Ah okay. So I have obtained the graph of this function and have added a picture of it in my initial question. Does this graph look correct? And also im still a bit confused on how you know that its between 0 and $\pi/2$

Comment: Circle is drawn correct but the radius should be drawn from the origin. That is how radius is a function of $\theta$ otherwise radius will be independent of $\theta$. $\cos 0^0 = 1, r = 3$, $\cos \pi/2 = 0, r = 0$...

Comment: Sorry Im still unsure where the $0\leq \theta \leq \pi/2$  Im just not understanding it at all.

Comment: Is it 3 as $cos(0) = 1$ ?

Comment: So do you just create the limits so that the value of $cos\theta$ goes between 0 and 1? So no matter the question, would the limits always be between 0 and $\pi/2$

Comment: It depends on the center of the circle. If it is on $(0,0)$ then distance of points on the circle from the origin always continues to be the same so to cover the circle, you have to go form $0$ to $2\pi$. If the center is on $y$-axis away from origin instead of on x-axis then it will be different.

Comment: So what if the function was $I_{6}=\int\int_{Q}x/\pi (x^{2}+y^{2}) dxdy$ $Q=\{(x,y)|(x-2)^{2} +y^{2} \leq(4), y\geq(0)}$ Would the centre be $(2,0)$  with the first integral looking like $\int_{0}^{2cos\theta} cos(\theta)/\pi$ but Im still unsure what the first integral limits would be.

Comment: Not $2\cos \theta$, $4\cos\theta$. Now as the circle is still on $x$-axis, away from the origin and $y \geq 0$, the range of $\theta$ would remain the same.

Comment: My suggestion - use different values of $r$ and draw $r \cos \theta$ and $r \sin \theta$ in desmos https://www.desmos.com/calculator. Use different range of $\theta$ to see how the circle builds.